# Android Studio Unreachable Statement

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a problem with compiling my project, in the Event Log it states that:

```
Error:(110, 9) error: unreachable statement
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The codes:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_analysis, container, false);
    InitializeAnalysisView(); // <-- [UNREACHABLE STATEMENT]
    return mRootView;
}

 private void InitializeAnalysisView(){
    mNameEditText = (EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_name2);
    mDescriptionEditText = (EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_descripion2);
    mGenderEditText = (EditText)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_gender2);
    mProfileImageButton = (ImageButton)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.capture_image_button2);
    mProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chooseanalysisimage();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((Gallery)activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(Constants.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```

The method `onAttach(Activity activity)` is deprecated. I'm running on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 with Android Version 4.4.2.
I've tried with solution that I found in the Internet but none of them work.

Comment: It is `unreachable` because you want it to execute after a `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are return immediately without assigning the inflated view to `mRootView` making the following statements not reachable

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_analysis, container, false);
```

should be

```
mRootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_analysis, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are return immediately without assigning the inflated view to mRootView making the following statements not reachable

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_analysis, container, false);
should be

mRootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_analysis, container, false);
copied !